# Is there a way to change the creation date of a GPG/PGP cert

Tags: pgp, gnupg

How can I modify the creation date of a GPG/PGP key?  I can [set the Creation-Date](http://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/) while creating a key.  But can I change this Creation-Date **after** the key was created?

I cannot find how to do this.

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: I can set the Creation-Date while creating a key: https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html  
But can I change this Creation-Date AFTER the key was created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible to change the creation date of a PGP key, because the creation date is part of the Public and Private Key Packet.

The OpenPGP Standard ([RFC4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880)) says

[5.5.2. Public-Key Packet Formats](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.5.2)

> (snip)
>
> A version 4 packet contains:
>
> ```
> - ...
> - A four-octet number denoting the time that the key was created.
> - ...
> ```

[5.5.3.  Secret-Key Packet Formats](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.5.3)

> (snip)
>
> The packet contains:
>
> ```
> - A Public-Key or Public-Subkey packet, as described above.
> ```

Also regarding signatures, the specification says under section [5.2.2.  Version 3 Signature Packet Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.2):

> The concatenation of the data to be signed, the signature type, and **creation time from the Signature packet** (5 additional octets) is hashed. The resulting hash value is used in the signature algorithm. The high 16 bits (first two octets) of the hash are included in the Signature packet to provide a quick test to reject some invalid signatures.

As you also added, in the GnuPG documentation under "[Unattended GPG key generation](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Unattended-GPG-key-generation.html)" the documentation specifically says:

> Ceation-Date: iso-date
>
> Set the creation date of the key as stored in the key information and **which is also part of the fingerprint calculation.**

---

As you may understand by now, editing the creation date of your current key and keeping the ability to encrypt, decrypt and sign with the key is impossible. Simply because the date is used as part of the key.

Comment: You can very well change the timestamp (fiddling with the bits); but as already mentioned the result is _another key_ (or better, the same public/private key pair with another fingerprint; thus all certifications being invalidated).

Comment: @JensErat Indeed. I was assuming that the asker wanted the "same" key/fingerprint but with a different creation date.

Comment: @JensErat the only thing changes is just fingerprints?

Comment: Technically, only the fingerprints change, but as keys are identified by fingerprints, other OpenPGP users will see different keys (and fingerprints are also the target of certifications, thus you lose all incoming certifications).